# Not getting value from JSlider

Tags: java, swing, jslider, changelistener

I am using a JSlider in my program, and have implemented a ChangeListener for the same.

```
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
    {
        JSlider source=(JSlider) e.getSource();
        frame_value.setText(Integer.toString(source.getValue()));

        //Condition to change the frame_no only when user has stopped moving the slider
        if (!source.getValueIsAdjusting()) 
        {
            frame_no=(int) source.getValue()-1;
            if(frame_no<0)
                frame_no=0;
        }
        ....
}
```

What is happening is, that whenever the ChangeListener is called, the program just skips the if block, and goes to the code after that. I don't understand why is this happening. I am not able to get the correct value from the JSlider. Please help!!

PS: I don't know if this is the reason, but recently I have set the UI of the JSlider to place the tick where I click it. I don't know if that is responsible for it or not. Here is the code:

```
slider.setUI(new MetalSliderUI() {
                protected void scrollDueToClickInTrack(int direction) {
                    int value = HEVC_Analyzer.slider.getValue(); 

                   value = this.valueForXPosition(HEVC_Analyzer.slider.getMousePosition().x);
                   HEVC_Analyzer.slider.setValue(value);
                }
            });
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have posted only the problem part here..the problem is the fact that this part of the code isn't executing..

Comment: *"I have posted only the problem part here."* Until you know the answer, how do you **know** that code is the **cause** of the problem?  I don't intend poring over uncompilable code snippets to try and determine whether that might be the case here, ..but you you might get lucky.  Otherwise, **post an SSCCE.**

Answer (score 5):

Must be something wrong in your code, since it's working fine in this example :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class SliderChangeEffect extends JFrame
{
    private JSlider slider;
    private int count = 0;
    private ChangeListener changeListener = new ChangeListener()
    {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ce)
        {
            JSlider slider = (JSlider) ce.getSource();
            if (!slider.getValueIsAdjusting())
                System.out.println(slider.getValue());
        }
    };

    private void createAndDisplayGUI()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationByPlatform(true);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setOpaque(true);

        slider = new JSlider(0, 10, 5);
        slider.setMajorTickSpacing(2);
        slider.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
        slider.addChangeListener(changeListener);

        contentPane.add(slider);

        getContentPane().add(contentPane);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new SliderChangeEffect().createAndDisplayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, me too waiting for the SSCCE, but since I was void of one, so tried my hands, and it is working, so pasted my code here :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the String.valueOf() and the event.MouseReleased().

```
 private void jSlider1MouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try {

        String valueOf = String.valueOf(jSlider1.getValue());
        jLabel1.setText(valueOf);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```